# CQ5 workflow inbox notifications persisting after workflow finished

Tags: workflow, aem

I've implemented a custom workflow in Adobe CQ5.6, similar to http://blogs.adobe.com/learningwem/2011/11/30/cq5-4-workflow-example-approve-reject-by-the-reviewer/

I'm using CQ5 inbox notifications only -- no email notifications.

The problem is, after the Approver selects either "Approve" or "Reject", the inbox notification does not get removed, even though the workflow continues / completes.

There doesn't seem to be an option to manually delete a notification, unless you go into crxde and delete the nodes. So the main concern here is that notifications will quickly pile up, making it confusing to figure out which ones are current, and ultimately clogging up the app.

This only seems to happen at this exact step in the workflow. The Author's notifications disappear once they've been dealt with, as you would expect.

Has anyone had anything like this happen before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something about the way I worded this question helped me figure out the answer.

> The Author's notifications disappear ... as you would expect

This made me think it might be a user permission problem rather than anything to do with the workflow step.

I confirmed this by switching the roles of the two user types, (so the Approver starts the workflow and the Author must approve the change). As I guessed, it was any notification assigned to the Approver, rather than notifications generated by that particular workflow step, which were not disappearing.

Specifically, the permission that was missing was for `/etc/workflow/instances`. I allowed all methods for that user, and my problem is resolved.

You can edit permissions via /useradmin.html in your CQ5 instance (in my case, `http://localhost:4502/useradmin.html` )